# daemons running with workflow?

Tags: snakemake

It's common these days to have to run daemons alongside a workflow. For example, deep learning jobs require parameter servers and hyperparameter optimization servers. I don't see any obvious supported way of doing this in Snakemake.

I could put code into the Snakefile that starts up a daemon when the workflow starts and kills it when it exits. I could also define a daemon as a rule that generates a daemon.pid file and have rules that need the daemon depend on that file.

Neither of those are ideal though, because they really don't express the intent of the daemon in the workflow. On top of that, while the .pid file approach may start up a daemon only as needed, it doesn't shut it down when it's not needed anymore.

How do people deal with this in their workflows?

Ideally, there would be a separate declaration for a "daemon", and it would get started just before the first rule that depends on the daemon starts, and it gets shut down when no more rules need it. Other workflow systems take that approach. Is there anything like it in Snakemake?

Answer (score 1):

Granted I've never used daemons, from my understanding I don't see your situation as particularly complicated.

One option could be to use the [onstart/onsuccess/onerror](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#onstart-onsuccess-and-onerror-handlers) handlers. Of course, this would start the daemon right at the beginning of the pipeline and stop it at the end, which may be undesirable.

Alternatively, make the first rule requiring the daemon depend on `daemon.start`. Then, the last rule requiring the daemon should touch a `daemon.end` file which triggers the stopping of the daemon. Something like:

```
rule all:
    input:
        'foo.txt',
        'daemon.end',

rule start_daemon:
    output:
        touch('daemon.start'),
    shell:
        r"""
        start-daemon
        """

rule do_stuff_with_daemon:
    input:
        'daemon.start',
    output:
        'foo.txt',
    shell:
        r"""
        do stuff with daemon
        """

rule stop_daemon:
    input:
        'foo.txt',
    output:
        touch('daemon.end'),
    shell:
        r"""
        stop-daemon
        """
```